Why this dipole antenna has 75$\Omega$ to 300$\Omega$ matching network in it?
I have bought this antenna in the thrift market.

It seemingly is a dipole for FM radio bands - both telescopic arms extend around 1.5m total. But it is connected in a strange way - in the connector there is a transformer that transforms 75$\Omega$ to 300$\Omega$. Also this is marked on the connector.
It's a simple dipole, twin wire connects directly to telescopic elements, why 300$\Omega$ though? I would understand if it was a folded dipole, but now it looks strange. Why would designers come up with such solution?
Plug is old school coaxial.


What kind of plug does it have on the end? How long is the twin line cable?

Twin wire cable length is 0.72m (1/4 $\lambda$ ?)

If twin wire transmission line is a 1/4 $\lambda$ transformer, then it is expected that antenna impedance is 1200$\Omega$ - does not make more sense than before ;)

That looks more like an old set of rabbit ears for a TV. :)

What you bought is a TV antenna. At one point, VHF TV signals were transmitted on two bands: 47–68 MHz or 54–88 MHz (band I in region 1 and region 2) and 174–240 MHz (band III). That antenna is a compromise between those two bands. FM broadcast signals (band II) fall between the two TV bands at 87–108 MHz. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_antenna#Rabbit_ears for a picture that looks a lot like your antenna.
Early TV antennas used folded dipoles with an impedance of 300Ω. That became a standard, and 300Ω twin-lead was used to connect the TV to the antenna. However, coaxial cable later gained favor over twin-lead. TV coaxial cable has an impedance of 75Ω. That's why there's a converter: it's meant to convert a 300Ω antenna that's connected via 300Ω twin-lead to the coaxial connector on the TV set, which is 75Ω.
And just to make this on-topic for amateur radio: the 6m band and the 4m band are in band I, while the 1.25m band is in band III. You should be able to receive frequencies in those bands with that antenna.

Here’s the deal with receive-only antennas: a lot of what you know about impedance matching goes right out the window. And it’s not because the laws of physics suddenly stop working. But really, it’s just a matter of engineering priorities. And in this little corner of the world, the priorities are very different, and the rules are, shall we say, flexible.
Take a V-shaped dipole antenna with a 50-ohm impedance, hooked up to a 300-ohm feedline. You’ll get a VSWR of 6, which sounds pretty bad. If you were transmitting 100 watts, half of that would bounce back (return loss) and mess with your amplifier. That’s why they talk about SWR like a broken record. But when you’re just receiving a tiny microwatt of signal? The SWR doesn’t matter. You lose half of the microwatt (mismatch loss), but it doesn’t affect much. The AGC  may make a flinch, but you won't know. That's the textbook definition of "doesn't matter."
When we talk about a dipole, it is often a straight-line dipole of half wavelength. However, this antenna is neither a straight-line nor half-wavelength long. When the angle is reduced, the impedance drops. When each element becomes longer than 1/4-wavelength, the impedance increases sharply (including the reactance component). The impedance is a lot more variable since it is placed indoors. There is not much point in getting these things exactly. The 4:1 balun is close enough.
Also, few good cheap and performant wideband transformer cover VHF/UHF between 1:1 and 4:1. So the real choice is between 1:1 and 4:1. Even that, doesn't matter that much in this case. It is more important to do the balanced-unbalanced conversion than get the impedance ratio exactly right.

So it is assumed by the manufacturer that final antenna impedance when placed into its destined position will be high - in the order of 300$\Omega$? Note that I am interested in particular technical decisions made when designing this antenna in principle i.e. why a dipole that has nominal impedance of 72$\Omega$ is connected via 300$\Omega$ line.

What I answered is that impedance matching is not that important in this case because dipole impedance is not always 72 ohm but rather much higher if the element is longer. The impedance is more variable depending on the number of factors and there is not much point in worrying about it in receive-only antenna. They probably would've used something 100 or 200ohm balanced cable if commonly available. The coax is too stiff for a lightweight indoor antenna.
